# Python & Pandas: How to address NaN values in a loop?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, nan

With Python and Pandas I'm seeking to take values from CSV cells and write them as txt files via a loop. The structure of the CSV file is:

```
user_id,    text,   text_number
0,  test text A,    text_0
1,      
2,      
3,      
4,      
5,  test text B,    text_1
```

The script below successfully writes a txt file for the first row - it is named text_0.txt and contains `test text A`.

```
import pandas as pd

df= pd.read_csv("test.csv", sep=",")

for index in range(len(df)):
     with open(df["text_number"][index] +  '.txt', 'w') as output:
        output.write(df["text"][index])
```

However, I receive an error when it proceeds to the next row:

```
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not float
```

I'm guessing the error is generated when it encounters values it reads as `NaN`. I attempted to add the `dropna` feature per the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) like so:

```
import pandas as pd

df= pd.read_csv("test.csv", sep=",")

df2 = df.dropna(axis=0, how='any')

for index in range(len(df)):
     with open(df2["text_number"][index] +  '.txt', 'w') as output:
        output.write(df2["text"][index])
```

However, the same issue persists - a txt file is created for the first row, but a new error message is returned for the next row: `KeyError: 1`.

Any suggestions? All assistance greatly appreciated.

Comment: `output.write(str(df["text"][index]))` ?

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately, same `KeyError: 1` error is generated.

Comment: What is the index of `df`? `index` needs to be a valid index of the dataframe not a positional indexer. It maybe `'1'` not `1`.

Comment: Thanks - could you elaborate? What would I need to do to establish a valid index?

Comment: Try `df = df.fillna('')`, do you still have an error? NB. You can do it before or after the `dropna`, depending on whether or not you want a file for NA rows.

Comment: Also, to iterate over the rows, do `for key, row in df.iterrows():`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you are creating a range index which is not necessarily in the data frame's index. For your use case, you can just iterate through rows of data frame and write to the file.

```
for t in df.itertuples():
    if t.text_number:           # do not write if text number is None
        with open(t.text_number +  '.txt', 'w') as output:
            output.write(str(t.text))
```